# use copy_to_user fail in timer handler function,why?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, copy

If I use copy_to_user in ioctl function, i can copy the data to the user space, but if I put the copy_to_user into the timeout handler function, copy_to_user can not be successful. Why?

```
    #include <linux/init.h>
    ...

    #define  GLOBAL_MEMSIZE 0x1000//4K
    ...
    static struct timer_list mytimer;
    ...

    typedef struct globalmem_dev{
        struct cdev cdev;
        unsigned char mem[GLOBAL_MEMSIZE];
    } Glo_dev, *Pglo_dev;

    Pglo_dev globalmem_devp;//global pointer
```

If I put copy_to_user in here, I can not copy the data to user correctly

```
    /*Timeout handler function*/
    static void timer_func(unsigned long data)
    {
        int retc = 0;
        retc = copy_to_user((void __user *)data, globalmem_devp->mem, 8);
        if(retc)
        {
            printk("timer_func------->copy_to_user fail\n");
        }
        mod_timer(&mytimer, jiffies + 2*HZ);

    }


    /*file open function*/
    static int hello_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
    {
        printk("hello open!\n");
        file->private_data = globalmem_devp;
        return 0;
    }
    /*file close function*/
    static int hello_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
    {

        del_timer_sync(&mytimer);
        printk("hello closed\n");
        return 0;

    }
```

The copy_to_user work fine in the ioctl function

```
    /*ioctl*/
    static long int globalmem_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
    {

        /*if(copy_to_user((void __user *)arg, globlmem_devp->mem, 8))
        {
             printk("copy_to_user fial\n");
        }*/
        setup_timer(&mytimer, timer_func, arg);
        mytimer.expires = jiffies + HZ;
        add_timer(&mytimer);

        return 0;
    }

    static struct file_operations hello_ops = {
        ...
    };

    /*init function*/
    static int __init hello_init(void)
    {
        ...
        globalmem_devp = kmalloc(sizeof(Glo_dev), GFP_KERNEL);//
        if(NULL == globalmem_devp)
        {
            return -ENOMEM; 
        }
        ...
        return 0;
    }        

    static void  __exit hello_exit(void)
    {
        ...
    }

    MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
    MODULE_AUTHOR("test");

    module_init(hello_init);
    module_exit(hello_exit);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`copy_to_user()` copies the data into the memory of the current user-space process, so it can be used only in some code that has been called from such a process.

An interrupt handler can run at any time, so there might be no current process, or worse, the current process is some other process.

Comment: Also, `copy_to_user()` can sleep, which is not allowed in an interrupt handler.